# datepicker with default value that is not shown

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

In WPF c#, I have a datepicker which holds a date time that can be null.
I want that if the date is null - When the calendar is opened - to show decade between 1960-1969. If the date time has value to show the date, but first open it in decades view.

I did like this but it does not open to me the calendar on decades and the value is not 1960

```
<Style x:Key="styleCalendar" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <!-- Wrapping in ViewBox will enlarge calendar of that size.-->
                <Viewbox Height="500"
                     Width="500">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="DisplayMode" Value="Decade"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you set the default value.  Where are you trying to set the default value?

Comment: Also, what does your actual Calendar element declaration look like?